# I created a local FTP site using Windows 10's built-in FTP server. However I can't download any files from it

Tags: windows, windows-10, ftp

I set it up with anonymous authentication enabled and basic authentication disabled, but I'm still prompted for a username and password when I navigate to e.g. ftp://localhost/MyFile.7z. Not knowing what to enter, I hit cancel, and then the file tries to download, but instead of the actual file, I get a dummy file with zero bytes. How do I get the file to actually download? And what can I do about that login screen?

Comment: Have you tried to leave it blank and click "Ok"?

Comment: If I do that, the prompt just reappears.